# Top-bar Drowndown Links Not Working

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation-5

I have the top-bar nav all setup and the dropdowns are displaying as expected. However, when I click on a dropdown link, the dropdown just disappears. The page does not advance to the URI as expected.

I'm stumped...

```
<section class="top-bar-section second-row">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><span> Alert Central</span></a></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span> Analytics</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="analytics.html">System Status</a></li>
                <li><a href="analytics-my-use.html">My Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="analytics-user-use.html">My User's Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="analytics-account.html">Account Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i><span> Filter Management</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="keywords.html">Keywords</a></li>
                <li><a href="keywords-categories.html">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span> User Management</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="user.html">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="user-roles.html">Roles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add **data-topbar** in `<section>` tag ?

```
<section data-topbar class="top-bar-section second-row">
```

Comment: I ended up fixing this but don't recall the fix, unfortunately.

Comment: In order to help other people who will have the same issue, mark this answer as solved if add data-topbar in your code work

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I certainly would mark it as solved if I was certain that adding data-topbar fixed it; however, the reality is that I don't remember what the fix was, otherwise I would post it. I believe it was a CSS issue, but am not certain.